# "month is not defined" Why?

Tags: python, function, calculator

Not the same question. his issue was with the variable being produced by input. my problem is the variable itself. 'MONTH' is not defined when Month is set to = input. My question: Prompt : # of month born Input ---> 1 January | | name error 'month is not defined' His: Name=input -----> input 'dude' error: 'DUDE IS NOT DEFINED' Not the same at all... He also uses Python 2.xx I'm using 3.4.3

> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > day born
> > >        input day #    1
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:/Python34/Astrology calc build 2.py", line 43, in 
> > >           print (month)
> > >       NameError: name 'month' is not defined

```
def calculate():
    month=input('   # of month born    ')
    if month == '1':
        print ("January")
        return "January"
    elif month == '2':
        print   ("February")
        return "February"
    elif month == '3':
        print  ("March")
        return "March"
    elif month == '4':
        print  ("April")
        return "April"
    elif month == '5':
        print   ("May")
        return "May"
    elif month == '6':
        print("June")
        return ("June")
    elif month == '7':
        print ("July")
        return "July"
    elif month == '8':
        print("August")
        return "August"
    elif month == '9':
        print("september")
    return "September"
    elif month == '10':
        print("October")
        return "October"
    elif month == '11':
        print ("November")
        return "November"
    elif month == '12':
        return "December"
        print ("December")
    else:
        return calculate()
print('day born')
day=input(' input day #    ')
print (month)
calculate()
```

Comment: @CoryKramer 
Not the same question.
his issue was with the variable being produced by input.
my problem is the variable itself. 

'MONTH' is not defined when 
Month is set to = input.

My question:

Prompt : # of month born
Input ---> 1
January
|
|
name error 'month is not defined'

His:

Name=input
-----> input 'dude'
error:  'DUDE IS NOT DEFINED'

Not the same at all...
He also uses Python 2.xx
I'm using 3.4.3

Comment: `month` is not global, you cannot access `month` here as it's defined in `calculate()` and you call `calculate` after print `month`

Comment: BTW `import calendar; print calendar.month_name[3]` will print March

Answer (score 0):

These 4 lines are executed first:

```
print('day born')
day=input(' input day #    ')
print (month)
calculate()
```

So in your `print (month)` command (line 3), *month* has not yet been defined.

Also, if you want to print what calculate() returns, in addition to printing in calculate(), then you need to `print (calculate())` or set the response of the function to a variable, and print it later

Answer (score 0):

Month is defined in your calculate() function and you are calling it outside calculate() function that is why you are getting this error

```
print('day born')
day=input(' input day #    ')
print (month) # month is not defined outside function that's why your getting that error 
calculate()
```

Solution:

```
#Solution
def calculate():
    month=input('   # of month born    ')
    if month == '1':
        print ("January")
        return "January"
    elif month == '2':
        print   ("February")
        return "February"
    elif month == '3':
        print  ("March")
        return "March"
    elif month == '4':
        print  ("April")
        return "April"
    elif month == '5':
        print   ("May")
        return "May"
    elif month == '6':
        print("June")
        return ("June")
    elif month == '7':
        print ("July")
        return "July"
    elif month == '8':
        print("August")
        return "August"
    elif month == '9':
        print("september")
        return "September"
    elif month == '10':
        print("October")
        return "October"
    elif month == '11':
        print ("November")
        return "November"
    elif month == '12':
        return "December"
        print ("December")
    else:
        return calculate()

print('day born')
day=input(' input day #    ')
month=calculate()
print(month)
```